# Why are state changes in my custom hook not being read?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-state

I'm building an audio player in React and I'm using a custom hook (`useQueueHandler`) to handle the logic of adding songs to the queue, skipping songs, etc.

I store the queue as state in `useQueueHandler` and pass down to my component a `loadNextSong` function which checks if there's a song in my queue and if so it changes the `currentSong` to the first song in queue. But the `loadNextSong` function can't see the songs I add to the queue.

I'm aware that a re-render is needed to see state changes, but I've tried forcing a state change in my `loadNextSong` function before checking the queue and I still can't see the updated queue state so I might not understand how or where I need to do a re-render.

Edit: Sorry, the code that actually runs the addSongToQueue function is in another component. But for simplicity I've added a button so you can see a static song being pushed as an example

AudioPlayer.js component

```
import useQueueHandler from "../hooks/useQueueHandler.js";

const AudioPlayer = () => {
const {userQueue, loadNextSong, addSongToQueue} = useQueueHandler()

return (
<div>
   <div>
     <button onClick={() => addSongToQueue({songTitle : "Angeles"})}
   </div>
   <div>
     <button onClick={() => loadNextSong()}></button>
   </div>
</div>
)
```

useQueueHandler custom hook

```
export default function useQueueHandler() {
   const [currentSong, newCurrentSong] = useState({});
   const [userQueue, setUserQueue] = useState([]);

   const addSongToQueue = (song) => {
      setUserQueue((prevState) => [...prevState, song]);
   }

   const loadNextSong = () => {
      if (userQueue.length > 0) {
         console.log(userQueue)
      }
   }

return {userQueue, loadNextSong, addSongToQueue}

}
```

Comment: Some details are missing here...nothing in the code you posted populates the `userQueue`.  Can you update your question please?

Comment: Your first `button` tag isn't closed, and your main component is missing a closing brace.  Other than that, the code works just fine, maybe there's something wrong with your build environment.